# AS3 / Flash - Add event listener in custom class of a button - Error 1061

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, addeventlistener

I'm getting an error whilst trying to add an event listener to a class of a Button on my stage.

> 1061: Call to a possibly undefined method addEventListener through a reference with static type Class.

On my stage i have a Button with the instance name stopBtn, this is also exported to an actionscript class called classes.stopBtn (stopBtn.as in a folder called 'classes'). The button is on the first keyframe in the main timeline, in a layer with other buttons on that layer

The error is on line 10 of the stopBtn.as file:

```
package  classes {

    import flash.display.SimpleButton;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class stopBtn extends SimpleButton {

        public function stopBtn() {
            stopBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, stopButtonFunction); 
        }

        function stopButtonFunction(event:MouseEvent):void  {           
                MovieClip(root).trackPosition = 0;
                MovieClip(root).mySoundChannel.stop();
                MovieClip(root).playPause.gotoAndPlay(2);
        }   

    }

}
```

I have found many threads for the error code 1061 but non of them seem to relate to my problem!

I have tried to ensure all event types are imported by using

```
Import flash.events.*; but this makes no difference.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code should be like

```
package  classes {

    import flash.display.SimpleButton;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class stopBtn extends SimpleButton {

        public function stopBtn() {
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, stopButtonFunction); 
        }

        function stopButtonFunction(event:MouseEvent):void  {           
                MovieClip(root).trackPosition = 0;
                MovieClip(root).mySoundChannel.stop();
                MovieClip(root).playPause.gotoAndPlay(2);
        }   

    }

}
```

Comment: I see what you did there! so because this class is especially for the Button 'stopBtn' i dont need to define stopBtn. before the event listener, it already knows im working with stopBtn.

Thankyou! :)

Comment: @TomFrom, you are wrong. When you wrote `stopBtn.add...`, the compiler took `stopBtn` as the class name (`public class stopBtn extends SimpleButton {`. When you removed that stopBtn, the compiler takes it as an implied reference to the object of the class. You can explicitly specify this using the `this` keyword.

Comment: you do not need add this, cause it is equal this.addEven... and addEvent... in any of class methods

Comment: @zaynyatyi, I doubt you read my full comment... I specifically wrote that addEventListener alone will take an implied `this.`

Answer (score 3):

This one should be pretty obvious. You are trying to add an event listener to the class, not the object.

```
 stopBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, stopButtonFunction);
```

`stopBtn` is the name of the class you have created. To add the event listener to the instance, modify your code to

```
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, stopButtonFunction);
```

That will ensure that you add the event listener to the button object, and not the class like you were trying to (It isn't allowed, as you saw, because it makes no sense)

Comment: "To add the event listener to the instance, use".... what? There seems to be something missing from this solution.

Comment: whoops, that happened mostly because I wrote this answer in 2 sittings and lost my train of thought between the two :P